# Accessible values, 0:00 as a duration not a time, 1/12/2023 as a date, etc

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have some html text which the NVDA screen reader (via the speech viewer) shows as the below text

```
row 9  Tue 28/11/23
First Hours 6:00
Second Hours 0:00
Third Hours 0:00  column 7
```

and reads aloud like so

```
row 9  Tue 28 slash 11 slash 23
First Hours six
Second Hours zero o'clock
Third Hours zero o'clock
 column 7
```

i.e. it thinks 6:00 is a duration, 0:00 is a time (it's not), and it doesn't recognise the date

I can't find any aria markers to indicate to the screen reader what the values actually mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is . . . to leave it as it is and do nothing.

You may be tempted to replace the text that you feel incorrectly read with a correction in full, using the visually-hidden+aria-hidden technique:

```
<span aria-hidden="true">Text that was incorrectly read</span>
<span class="visually-hidden">Replacement visible only by screen readers</span>
```

However, it's a very bad idea, especially for numbers, dates, times, etc. for several reasons, among the following:

- For a braille user, it's much longer, and a lot less understandable, to read "0 minutes, 0 seconds" in full text rather than "0:00"
- Everything isn't read exactly the same by all people, and you shouldn't impose your way. Some people prefer to have the text read as it is without any interpretation for example. By imposing your way, you are very likely to create more problems than solve.
- Screen reader users are used to pronounciation quirks and understand them well, so you don't need to care specially. Once again, by imposing your way, you are very likely to create more problems than solve.
- Different screen readers and even different voices threat numbers, dates and times differently, so maybe it's a problem for you, but not for other people. For example, I have no problem with Jaws with Eloquence synthesizer, which says "zero hours" for "0:00".
- Blind users aren't stupid, and can understand even if what is read don't match exactly what was meant. For example, "3:12" is read as "3 hours 12", but it's in principle obvious from the context if it means in fact 3 minutes and 12 seconds and not 3 hours and 12 minutes.

In general, replacing some text by another alternative text is a bad idea and is likely to create more problems than solve.

Comment: Thanks for that. I do find it very surprising though given the drive to the semantic web. A button is a button not a hyperlink, don't use tables for layout, etc, but it's ok to not have data types.

Comment: There's schema.org, but it's much higher level than telling if 0:00 is h/m or m/s. There's also `<time>` element, as well as epub3 specific refinements, but again, no way to specify that. Screen readers anyway don't do anything special with all that additional semantic info currently. There's maybe something to do to help screen readers, but as far as I know today, nothing standard went so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth considering if the text needs to change instead of trying to fix the issue with ARIA or other metadata. A maxim of the practice of universal design is: accommodations made for a minority often end up benefiting the majority.

For example, this text isn't just problematic for assistive tech to interpret. I as a sighted user also struggle to know if `6:00` is a time or a duration, and what units the duration would be in. Likewise I've never seen a date in the format `28/11/23`, and date formats vary widely by region.

You could reformat durations to be presented in a format like `6h 7m` and dates could use the ISO standard of `2023-11-28`. Screen readers will likely have an easier time interpreting these as well.

There's also the [`<time>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) in HTML, which can be used to add machine-readable values to dates, times, and durations, which some screen readers will likely be able to use as well.

```html
<time datetime="PT2H30M">2h 30m</time>
<time datetime="2023-11-28">2023-11-28</time>
<time datetime="14:00">2pm</time>
```

Comment: Note that screen readers don't do anything special with `<time>`, and aren't very likely to do in the future. You are right, though, that 6h30mn is probably clearer for most people than 6:30. Concerning dates, however, assuming ISO format for everyone is still problematic in general, confusing or at least quite inconvenient (yyyy-mm-dd vs. yyyy-dd-mm vs. dd-mm-yyyy). The best is to provide an option so that the user can select the date format he/she wants, or better, base on system settings if possible.

Comment: @QuentinC It's incorrect to say "screen readers don't do anything special with `<time>`". [Some do, and will even translate and localize times, dates, and durations](https://www.jasha.eu/blogposts/2019/05/voiceover-safari-time-element.html). Additionally, leading with a 4-digit year significantly reduces ambiguity since there aren't any countries that use YYYY-DD-MM, and YYYY-MM-DD is the very popular international standard.

Comment: oh, sorry, I wasn't aware of that, as VoiceOver isn't my primary screen reader. Thank you for pointing this! Still, it's VO specific. Jaws and NVDA do nothing special with `<time>`. Otherwise, I don't agree for yyyy-mm-dd; Jaws uses its own engine to recognize date/times, it does recognize my own local format (dd.mm.yyyy) but doesn't recognize yyyy-mm-dd. Personally I still understand so I don't care much, but it might not be the case of all people.